# RDS Postgres DB IAM generate_db_auth_token not working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

In **AWS** I have an **RDS Postgres database**. The database has users that can connect via **IAM** (they have the **IAM_USER** role). The connection is achieved programmatically via **Python** and **Boto3**, e.g.:

**RDS Client setup**

```
self.rds = boto3.client(
    'rds',
    region_name = rds_region,
    aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key,
)
```

**Generating the token**

```
return self.rds.generate_db_auth_token(
    self.db_hostname,
    self.port,
    self.db_username,
    Region=self.region
)
```

A valid token is generated that enables a Postgres login when I use the AWS keys of an IAM user that pretty much has access to everything in AWS.

However when I use the AWS keys of a user that only has **AmazonRDSFullAccess** and **AmazonRDSDataFullAccess** a token is generated which looks similar to a valid one but is not accepted as a password when I attempt to login to Postgres, e.g.:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "test_iam_user"
```

This user can access all my RDS resources correctly as far as I can tell, it just doesn't generate a valid token.

I'd be grateful if anyone could tell what is the missing permission(s) and/or what I'm doing wrong.

It would also be good to know the best way to troubleshoot permission problems like these in AWS to find the specific permission that's preventing access.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

My fellow engineer Jun solved this!

What I was missing was the following permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-west-1:<aws_account_number>:dbuser:<rds_db_resource_id>/<postgres_user>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once this permission was added to the IAM user in conjunction with AmazonRDSFullAccess or AmazonRDSDataFullAccess, then a valid token was generated that could be used as a password to login to the RDS database.

Comment: One slight oddity is that the AWS console doesn't seem to like **rds-db**, it displays the warning/error message: ```This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.```